# DYMO label writer 'Invalid class string'

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com, dymo

#### I am trying to get my DYMO LabelWrite 450 Duo to print a label.

However, I am having trouble making the script do anyting. When I run the script below:

```py
    from win32com.client import Dispatch

    labelCom = Dispatch('Dymo.DymoAddIn')
    labelText = Dispatch('Dymo.DymoLabels')
    print(f"labelCom: {labelCom}")
```

##### I get the following error message:

```bash
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\lars\.virtualenvs\Labels-MxmV_EZi\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 84, in _GetGoodDispatch
        IDispatch = pythoncom.connect(IDispatch)
    pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
        labelCom = Dispatch('Dymo.DymoAddIn')
      File "C:\Users\lars\.virtualenvs\Labels-MxmV_EZi\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 118, in Dispatch
        dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch, userName, clsctx)
      File "C:\Users\lars\.virtualenvs\Labels-MxmV_EZi\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 104, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
        return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
      File "C:\Users\lars\.virtualenvs\Labels-MxmV_EZi\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 87, in _GetGoodDispatch
        IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch
    pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```

##### I am using:

- Windows 10: KB5027122
- dymo:DCDSetup1.4.5.1.exe, DYMO_Label_v.8_SDK_Installer.exe
- pyton 3.7

Pipfile:

```
  ...
  [packages]
  pywin32 = "*"
  [requires]
  python_version = "3.7"
  ...
```

##### I tried the following:

I re-installed both DCDSetup and SDK with no effect.
I downgraded from python 3.11 to 3.7, no effect.
I tried to run python as Admin, no effect.
I tried to find the dymo com name using regedit, but couldnt find it.
None worked.

NOTE: When I use the UI, the printer works just fine.
Has anyone a idea, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I see someone having the same problem 1 year ago here: https://www.reddit.com/r/dymo/comments/v14ilv/python_dymo550/ (error is in german, but it's the same error). Could the issue be the same where the Dymo machine model isn't supported by the SDK?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Its the same error, but there is no solution posted. Also it states, that it should work for the 450.

Comment: NOW I see that you said it was the "450". I totally overlooked that.

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with the product, but the `Invalid Class String` error means that the application has not registered the name `Dymo.DymoAddIn` in the Registry when the application was installed. One reason might be that the application was installed using insufficient privileges to write to the Registry. Maybe install the app again, but running as Admin?